# C++ Differences between Dynamic Variable and Undefined Memory

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am just now learning the concept of dynamic variables in C++. The first example I came across was the following.

```
  int *p1 = new int;
  std::cin >> *p1;
  *p = *p + 5;
  std::cout << *p1;
```

I was wondering what would happen if the pointer p1 did not point to a dynamic memory location and rather was uninitialized, which from my understanding is undefined behavior. So,

```
  int *p1;
  std::cin >> *p1;
  *p1 = *p1 + 7;
  std::cout << *p1;
```

I tried this and it did not work. It let me input an integer from console, but did not output anything. Why is that? Even if p1 is pointing to a random memory location, why can't I change the value of whatever it's pointing to? Why do I need to assign p to a 'new' memory location?

Comment: From my understanding, when p1 is uninitialized it could be pointing to literally anywhere. However, when you create a dynamic variable it is located in the heap, and behaves more predictably. You shouldn't ever de-reference an uninitialized pointer. I still want to see what others think about this.

Comment: So, are there some cases in which my second code block would work, say if the uninitialized variable randomly points to the heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things here:

- When you don't initialize a variable it is unspecified what its value will be (depends on your compiler, the compiler settings, your OS, the state of your machine at the time etc.). It's literally whatever happens to be on the stack at the time.
- Operating systems need to guarantee process isolation - meaning, if one process misbehaves, it doesn't take the whole system down, or affect other running processes. One of these things is memory protection. Each process has memory it is permitted to use. If the random address happens to fall outside this region, your program will crash.
- If the random address falls within the permitted area, then it could be "harmless" or you could corrupt your process stack, heap or any other number of things, leading to later mysterious crashes.
- Finally, it doesn't have to point to the heap or a `new` piece of memory - it could be on the stack.

Here's an example with the stack:

```
int x = 0;
int* p1 = &x;
std::cin >> *p1;
*p1 = *p1 + 7;
std::cout << *p1;
std::cout << x; // x and *p1 refer to the same value
```

Answer (score 4):

> It let me input an integer from console, but did not output anything.
>   Why is that?

If it wasn't due to the program crashing (as VorpalSword suggested), then perhaps when you overwrote (whatever word of memory you overwrote) that broke something in the stdout-mechanism that was depending on it retaining its original value.  The thing about undefined behavior is that it's undefined -- which is to say, exactly what will happen will depend on the exact details of how every potentially affected mechanism in the process works, and more precisely how it might fail when the preconditions it depends on have been violated.  In general, nobody tries to document or characterize the undefined behavior, because it would be an endless job, and there's no benefit to doing so in any case, because a program that invokes the undefined behavior needs to be fixed anyway.

> Even if p1 is pointing to a random memory location, why can't I change
>   the value of whatever it's pointing to?

Well, you *can* -- but by doing so, you've invoked undefined behavior, which means that nothing is guaranteed to work right after that, and if anything doesn't do what you wanted after that, the only person to blame is you :)

> Why do I need to assign p to a 'new' memory location?

Because if you're going to use a piece of memory, you'll want to use a piece of memory that no other bit of code is using for some other purpose.  Otherwise any changes you make to it will overwrite whatever value they had placed there (or vice versa), leading to unexpected/unhelpful behavior either in your logic or their logic, or both.

The 'new' operator breaks you off a bit of known-to-be-not-in-use-by-anyone-else memory from the heap, so that you can be sure that is available for your own private use only.  The 'delete' operator gives that memory back to the heap so that it can be re-used for other purposes after you are done with it.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which basically means anything can happen.  Typically, one of three things will actually happen: either the program will crash immediately, or it'll continue to work.  It might also work for awhile, but misbehave later.  But you can't rely on any particular outcome — undefined behavior means *anything* could happen.

Answer (score 1):

It probably seg faulted. Have you tried single stepping this in a debugger?